# What conditions does ]Save in Dyalog APL have?

Tags: macos, apl, dyalog

So I recently started learning about Dyalog APL and now I have a function that I would like to save, but when ever I try to use ]Save according to the help text provided by it I only get 'Invalid object' or 'DOMAIN ERROR' and sometimes just "Command interpreter returned failure code 1" as an Error, curiously even with the same command.
I'm currently using Dyalog 18.2 on Mac OS 13.

I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67747785/how-do-i-save-dyalog-apl-functions-in-a-text-file) through the Dyalog Configuration Guide and the User Manual unfortunately I have not found anything helpful, I suspect it might have to do with permissions but I haven't found anything about that yet either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`]Save` is part of SALT, which is gradually becoming outdated technology, with Link taking over most of its role. You should be able to save a function `myfn` with any of these three commands:

```
]export myfn /path/to/dir
]export myfn /path/to/dir/filename
]export myfn /path/to/dir/filename.ext
```

(`]Export` is part of Link — you can use `]link.export` instead, but just `]export` works too.)

The first will default to the filename `myfn.aplf`, the second will add an appropriate extension, `.aplf`.

Note that you cannot save tacit (primitive, derived, trains) functions to file, because we do not currently have a text representation for them.

If these fail, then there's likely something wrong with your install

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response, that did indeed solve my problem.

Comment: @Bnengon Great. Then consider accepting this answer using the checkmark.